# Daily alerts emails are not receiving From Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

Only 2 users are complaining that, they are not getting daily alert emails from one sub site (others are getting alerts). these 2 users are getting alerts emails from different sub sites from same site collection. We checked exchange server log, Yes exchange server not have their email ids. That means that SharePoint not sending emails to them.

Why they are getting alerts from different sub sites not from one particular site? How can I debug and solve this?

How can set log for alert emails in central admin? So I can check users emails are going or not.

Comment: what do you mean by "Yes exchange server not have their email ids"

Comment: We checked exhange server logs. we dont find email id that going out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together a [SharePoint alert troubleshooting guide](http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts/) - some problems can be hard to resolve but hope it helps.

If you're successfully receiving alerts from other sites then you can ignore the steps for checking your email infrastructure is setup correctly (relay allowed etc).

[image: SharePoint Alert troubleshooting guide]

Comment: This helped thanks.  Oddly the user was in a group that had contribute permission to the list and was not getting the alerts.  Added them directly with the same permissions and alerts started working.

Answer (score 1):

We recently had the same issue. Users were able to receive immediate alerts but were not receiving scheduled (daily or weekly) alerts.

We were able to [troubleshoot the alert problem](http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2009/11/20/alerts-in-sharepoint-troubleshooting-moss-wss.aspx) and found that running the stsadm command [updatealerttemplates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd278299%28office.12%29.aspx) ended up fixing the issue.

P.S. We also followed this with an `iisreset` for good measure, but not sure if this is required.